# CORS Between Spring Boot(Spring Security) and Enterprise Authentication applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I am getting CORS issue even after setting required headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `http://localhost:4200`, `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` and so on.

```
Response from previous request:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Special-Response-Header, Header2 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200 
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Special-Response-Header, Header2 
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600 
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Special-Response-Header, Header2 
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
Content-Length: 0 Date: Mon, 18 Jun 2018 13:03:46 GMT 
Expires: 0 
Location: <<Replace with Org Authentication URL>> 
Origin: http://localhost:4200 
Pragma: no-cache 
Set-Cookie: dtCookie=8$C38554BBC14802D7BCFE9A5E047AA962;domain=rbc.com;path=/ Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=26A7EB71BD36D31EFE6A701320DFA0C3;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly Set-Cookie: __VCAP_ID__=0a838736-ad8b-40b9-4aa5-e972; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: DENY X-Vcap-Request-Id: 61cc9d4e-29ba-4b11-7f0b-82ec01cbc0a6 X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Current Request :

```
GET <<Replace with Org Authentication Get method params>> 
HTTP/1.1 
Host: mrkdlvaiaas493.devfg.rbc.com:9443 
Connection: keep-alive 
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */* 
Origin: null 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36 Referer: http://localhost:4200/startBatch/2018-04-27 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Error :

```
Failed to <<Replace with Org Authentication URL>>: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: What version of spring boot.  Which approach did you use to enable CORS in your spring app?  The cross origin annotation?

Comment: @LucasHolt : Thank you, for your response. I am using Spring Boot 1.5.2. I tried annotating my local end points with CORS, setting configurations using WebMvcConfigurer(to update CorsRegistry) and adding custom filter class(to update response).

Answer (score 0):

Try declare a bean like this: (to enable cors)

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityBasicConfigurations {

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsOriginConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings( CorsRegistry registry ) {
            registry.addMapping( "/*" )
                    .allowedMethods( "*" )
                    .allowedOrigins( "http://localhost:4200" )
                    .allowedHeaders( "*" );
        }
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank for your response. I tried this one already and no luck.